# Python alter attribute of instance during initialization

Tags: python, class

Is it possible to alter attributes of instances during its initialization?

E. G the following code.

```
class Sensor() :
    def __init__(self) :
         self.name = 'pressure' 

Sensor1 = Sensor(name='pH')
```

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare you accept a `name` argument and then you need to explicitly update the appropriate attribute:

```py
class Sensor():
    def __init__(self, name='pressure'):
        self.name = name
```

Notice that I'm using `'pressure'` as a default value for the `name` argument in case the consumer does not provide it:

```py
a = Sensor()
print(a.name) # 'pressure'

b = Sensor(name='sensor')
print(b.name) # 'sensor'
```

`name` can also be provided as a positional argument:

```py
c = Sensor('some_name')
print(c.name) # 'some_name'
```

---

## A more generic approach

There's also a more generic approach (if the use cases requires it), which involves creating the attributes dynamically:

```py
class Sensor():
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         for attr, value in kwargs.items():
             setattr(self, attr, value)
```

Then you can do something like:

```py
d = Sensor(name='foo', temperature=70, active=True)
print(d.name)        # 'foo'
print(d.temperature) # 70
print(d.active)      # True
```

Answer (score 2):

Not like that, if you want to set the attribute you would have to do something like:

```
class Sensor() :
    def __init__(self, name='pressure') :
         self.name = name 

Sensor1 = Sensor(name='pH')
```

If not provided the name would be `pressure` but if name is given in the initialization it will be set to the one provided.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give a way to pass those and set default values. In your example, you just need to add a default.

```
 class Sensor() :
     def __init__(self,name='pressure') :
          self.name = name
```